# D3 Dynamically Changing Tick Format

Tags: d3.js

I am making a choropleth map.  When the user hovers over a polygon a simple line graph will be displayed reflecting data contained in that specific polygon.

The data contains a large degree of variation.  Some times the domain on the Y axis will be maximum of $400,000,000. In these cases I want to display the figure as "400M."  Thats easy enough!

But in some cases the data for a particular polygon might have a maximum value of $100,000 in those cases I would like to display "100K"

In some cases the data may only have a maximum value of $100....

How can I dynamically change the tick format to reflect the different domains that will be encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that all you need is to set the ticks to use SI:

```
.tickFormat(d3.format(".0s"));
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([10, 280]);
 
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale.domain([0, 100000000]))
 .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));
 
var gX = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,30)")
 .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

You can see how this format works for several different values:

```js
var format = d3.format(".2s");

console.log(format(10000000000))
console.log(format(100000000))
console.log(format(4786))
console.log(format(42))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Gerado Futado thanks. Silly me. Rather obvious really.